# Websockets disconnecting with code -1 with Too Tall Nate Java library

Tags: java, websocket, processing

I have a interactive paint app hosted at [paint.unubo.cloud](http://paint.unubo.cloud), and whenever I try to connect to it using processing and Too Tall Nate's Java websocket library, it immediately disconnects with disconnect code -1. I can't find anything about what the -1 means, and I have no idea how to fix it. Here is my code:

```
import processing.core.*; 
import processing.data.*; 
import processing.event.*; 
import processing.opengl.*; 

import org.java_websocket.client.WebSocketClient; 
import org.java_websocket.handshake.ServerHandshake; 
import java.net.URI; 

import java.util.HashMap; 
import java.util.ArrayList; 
import java.io.File; 
import java.io.BufferedReader; 
import java.io.PrintWriter; 
import java.io.InputStream; 
import java.io.OutputStream; 
import java.io.IOException; 

public class WebPaint extends PApplet {





Client client;
boolean isOpen = false;
int x = -50;
int y = -50;

public void setup() {

  background(100);
  fill(0);
  try {
    client = new Client(new URI("wss://paint.unubo.cloud/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=websocket"));
    client.connect();
  } 
  catch(Exception e) {
    println(e);
  }
}

public void draw() {
  ellipse(x, y, 10, 10);
}

public void mouseDragged() {
  if (isOpen) {
    client.send("42[\"message\",{\"x\":" + mouseX + ",\"y\":" + mouseY + "}]");
  }
}

public void keyPressed() {
  client.connect();
}
class Client extends WebSocketClient {
  public Client(URI serverURI) {
    super(serverURI);
  }
  public void onError(Exception e) {
    println(e);
  }
  public void onClose(int reason, String details, boolean remote) {
    println("Closed: " + reason + " " + details);
    isOpen = false;
    //exit();
  }
  public void onOpen(ServerHandshake hs) {
    println("Connected");
    isOpen = true;
  }
  public void onMessage(String message) {
    if (message.length() > 2 && message.substring(0, 2).equals("42")) {
      String data = message.substring(13, message.length() - 1);
      JSONObject json = JSONObject.parse(data);
      println(json.toString());
      x = json.getInt("x");
      y = json.getInt("y");
      ellipse(json.getInt("x"), json.getInt("y"), 10, 10);
    }
  }
}
  public void settings() {  size(600, 600); }
  static public void main(String[] passedArgs) {
    String[] appletArgs = new String[] { "WebPaint" };
    if (passedArgs != null) {
      PApplet.main(concat(appletArgs, passedArgs));
    } else {
      PApplet.main(appletArgs);
    }
  }
}
```